# Passing Variables to jqPlot Charts

Tags: jquery, variables, jqplot

I'm trying to source data from input fields to a simple jqPlot chart when the page loads.

Using the standard syntax, jqPlot works fine. For example:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[1,2,3,4,]]);
```

Using a variable causes the chart to, at best, only respond to the first integer in the variable. I think I'm close and suspect it's an issue with the numeric value/string quality of the Var.

Am I on the money here or am I trying to do something that's not possible?

HTML:

```
<div class="dataforchart"> <!-- VALUES -->
<input type="text" value="5">
<input type="text" value="2">
<input type="text" value="8">
<input type="text" value="1">
</div>
<div id="chart1"> <!-- CHART -->
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.dataforchart').each(function(){

str = '';
$(this).children("input").each(function() {
str = str + ', ' + $(this).val();
});

alert(str);
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[str]]);

});
```

I've found very similar problems on SO, however I have not found a working solution.

Update: I've made a demo if anyone would like to test: http://jsfiddle.net/fdKRw/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's an array, not a string, so just give it the array of points:

```
...
var points = [];
$(this).children("input").each(function(index) {
    points[index] = $(this).val();
});

var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1',[points]);
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdKRw/4/